# Cannot run flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I am trying to get my flutter project running.
When running main.dart I'm getting this error message which I don't understand.

```
Language Language: Dart doesn't participate in view provider com.jetbrains.lang.dart.psi.impl.DartExpressionCodeFragmentImpl$1{vFile=LightVirtualFile: /dummy.dart, content=VirtualFileContent{size=0}, eventSystemEnabled=true}: [Language: TEXT]
```

The code isn't syntax highlighted anymore. I had this problem in version 2021 AND 2022.
If somebody has an idea of what went wrong, please let me know :)

Comment: This can occur if the plugin you're using changes the parser but forgets to update the stubs version, then IntelliJ can get confused.

Answer (score -1):

The **Dart doesn't participate in view provider** error is caused due to invalid file associations. Your IDE is associating your dart files to another file extension.

In your **Settings -> Editor -> File Types**  check if your ***.dart** is associated to this and delete it.

[Example of such association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp6nZ.png)

Then search for **Dart** under the recognized file types and add ***.dart** under the file name patterns. With this *.dart* would be recognized as a dart file throughout your IDE.

This is a reference to the github issue where the solution was found
[Link to github issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6633)